# Why does the reference symbol (&) copies a value in this Rust syntax?

Tags: rust

I do not understand why the `&` in `&x` in the following Rust syntax actually copies the value behind a reference, hence, makes an owned value. In some sort, the `&` performs an "upgrade" of the value here, surprisingly. I expected that `&` would only create a reference (similar to the `ref` keyword) but never a copied version from a reference. To better demonstrate it, I provide a small example where rustc tells the actual type with an error message:

```rust
let opt: Option<u8> = Option::from(42_u8);
opt.filter(|x| {
    // compiler fails: says 'x' has type "&u8"
    let _: () = x;
    true
});
opt.filter(|&x| {
    // compiler fails: says 'x' has type "u8"
    let _: () = x;
    true
});
```

What is going on here? Any reference to the language documentation? This looks weird to me and I never saw this in my past four years with Rust.. or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

In expressions, `&` indeed takes a reference.

But in patterns, `&` dereferences a reference.

This is easy to remember if you see the symmetry:

```
let &x = &y; // Take reference on the expression, dereference on the pattern. At the end x == y.
```

[Here's the reference docs on reference patterns](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/patterns.html#reference-patterns).

Comment: yikes, seems you was 9 seconds faster than me in finding the actual answer. But thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in the reference in [Patterns/Reference patterns](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#reference-patterns).

A minimal example to see this kind of an "upgrade" is the following:

```rust
fn main() {
    match &5 {
        &x => {
            // compiles
            let _: i32 = x;
        }
    }
}
```